# serialize a class hierarchy into a file in matlab

Tags: xml, json, matlab

I have a class like this:

```
classdef Sub <Base
    properties (GetAccess = public, SetAccess = private)
        P2
    end
    methods (Access=public)
        function NewObj=Sub(P1)
            NewObj=NewObj@Base(P1);
            NewObj.P2=P1+1;
        end
        function SaveToFile(FileNamePath)
        end
        function ReadFromFile(FileNamePath)
        end
    end
end
```

and

```
classdef Base <handle
    properties (GetAccess = public, SetAccess = private)
        P1
    end
    methods (Access=public)
        function NewObj=Base(P1)
            NewObj.P1=P1;
        end
    end
end
```

As you can see I have two functions for saving and reading the object to a file and I want to implement it, but I can not write them.

I already tried to use xml and jsonlab without any success as they can not serialise classes into string.

Is there any library that can serialise a class into a string and read it back?

Comment: Any reason why you don't wanna use `save()` and `load()`?

Comment: @OlegKomarov Are they serialize to a text base file?

Comment: Yes, and you can read more here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/serializing-deserializing-matlab-data. I'd say you should elaborate a bit more on why you'd need another format other than `.mat`.

Comment: @OlegKomarov I may need to send it over a media that can not accept binary data. .mat is a binary format (save(filename) saves all variables from the current workspace in a MATLAB® formatted binary file (MAT-file) called filename. If filename already exists, save overwrites the file.) and is not suitable.

Comment: Call `struct()` on your object and then convert the structure to json.

Comment: @OlegKomarov Thanks. How can I convert from a struct to the object when I read it back from file?

Comment: You need to define a separate method, call it e.g. struct2myobj.